# Trouble with Responsive Mode on Elementor Pro

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design, responsive, elementor

I have two problems.

1. I want to know how to change the responsive mode preview for tablet, on my profile the preview is for 481px while on all the tutorial it’s 768px.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQHJR.jpg)
2. I’m having trouble with the content on the actual devices, on the preview appears in one way but in the actual device (mobile, ipad, etc) appears different, I have established all the sizes in %, so that it depends on the size of the screen, but don’t matter what I do, the content on my cellphone or other cellphones and ipads is showed different from what I see on the elementor page on my computer.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTmBt.jpg)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLE5r.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

1. Look for breakpoints at the settings. Note: mobile mode is for all smaller than mobile breakpoint width (Default: 768px) and tablet mode is from mobile width til tablet breakpoint (Default: 1025px)
2. Percentage isn't the best ways to set sizes. Try i.e. different margins in pixels for the different modes. At your screenshot the scroll bar makes the difference. You don't have it at the mobile devices but in the preview of your browser while editing with Elementor. You can try the recent Elementor Beta Release, here you change the preview dimensions easily by handles - more infos here: https://flextensions.com/599/elementor-v3-2-beta-release/